# Ignoring variables in shell script while using cat>file.sh<<EOF ... EOF syntax

Tags: perl, shell, embed, cat

I have a question regarding embedding script files within a shell script. I often have a need to create a single shell script that unpacks other scripts, but really dislike having to comment out all of the embedded script's variables. Example of contents of my shell script:

```
echo "Hello world"
pwd

cat>embedded_perl_script<<EOF
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
\$input = \$ARGV[0];
my \$argc;
\$argc = @ARGV;
print \$input
EOF

perl embedded_perl_script
echo "Finished!"
```

This code works fine, but I would really like a way to avoid commenting out all of the embedded perl script's variables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo "Hello world"
pwd

cat>embedded_perl_script<<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$input = $ARGV[0];
my $argc;
$argc = @ARGV;
print $input
EOF

perl embedded_perl_script
echo "Finished!"
```

Note that the `EOF` had changed to `'EOF'` =)

**Note** : this technique is named *here-doc*

Comment: Full name is actually “here document”, but the rest is correct.